# React Router V6 doesn't show up the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to use react router v6. However when try those routes below, it just shows an empty page. What could be the problem ?

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/home';

function App() {
  return <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/hi' element={<div>hi</div>} />
      <Route path='/bye' element={<div>bye</div>} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>

}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default function Home(){
    return <h1>Home</h1>
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: I don't get any error but page shows nothing

Comment: when you go to "/hi" path does that show `div with hi` ?

Comment: It doesn't show that way either

Answer (score 0):

It works. Check your libraries or Re-Install the Package(npm install).

After deleting package.lock file and node_modules

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
// import Home from "./home";

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/hi" element={<div>hi</div>} />
        <Route path="/bye" element={<div>bye</div>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```